# Resource file in aspx page "Eval" syntax

Tags: asp.net, syntax, localization, globalization

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a id="btnShowPopup" runat="server" class="thickbox" title='<%# Eval("DB_TRAK_NO", "Details for Trak No.  {0}") %>>
            View
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

My Global resouce file name is Resource.resx and Resource.zh-CN.resx, 
key for "Details for Trak No" is "DetailsforTrakNo" in resource files. How can I push the Chinese characters when the culture is Chinese. I dont know the syntax to write title in anchor tag.. can you pls help me in this.

Regards,
Abhi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a id="btnShowPopup" runat="server" class="thickbox" title='<%$ Resource:Resources, DetailsforTrakNo %>'>
    View
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try [<%$ Resources:YourResourceTypeName, Key %>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx) syntax to add global resource expression.

```
title='<%$ Resources:Resource, DetailsforTrakNo %>'
```

Comment: <a id="btnShowPopup" runat="server" title='<%#  <%$ Resources:ResourceType, Key %> Eval("DB_TRAK_NO", "Details for Trak No.  {0}") %>> --------------- ????

Answer (score 1):

you can also use

```
Text='<%#Eval(GetLocalResourceObject("gvstrCompanyName").ToString())%>'
```