# Dynamically resolve a resource key

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I would like to insert a string (key) into a `'<%$ Resources:resFile, someKey %>'` statement dynamically at runtime.

Right now I have this:

```
 <asp:Label runat="server" id="lbl" Text='<%$ Resources:resFile, someKey %>'/>
```

which is useless to me, because the key "someKey" is static and will always converge to the same x translations.

I've tried doing things like this:

```
 <asp:Label runat="server" id="lbl" Text='<%$ Resources:resFile, '<%#Eval("someProperty")%>' %>'/>
```

But this doesn't quite compile. I'm not sure if you can have nested `<%%>` statements, so thats why i'm asking here.
I've also tried a variety of things with `GetGlobalResourceObject()` but that doesn't do what i want either.

The thing is that i am binding a list to a repeater, and one of the items in the datasource will contain the key that will match a key in the resource files.

If anyone knows a way how to achieve this, be it with nested `<%%>` statements or be it any other way, i'd be happy to try it out.

Comment: single quotes  are breaking the statement: '<%$ Resources:resFile, '<%#Eval("someProperty")%>' %>', as far I guess you do not need again to put <% at inner end. Use Eval directly instead Like: '<%$ Resources:resFile, #Eval("someProperty") %>'

Comment: @Neha I get "The resource object with key '#Eval("myprop")' was not found." It seems like the eval is not being compiled and that it is being interpreted as a literal string..Any other ideas? Thanks already tho.

Comment: how about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626080/resource-file-in-aspx-page-eval-syntax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this in Code-Behind on the ItemDataBound Event.

```
Label lv = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl");


ResourceManager resMngr = new ResourceManager(typeof(SupertextCommon.Default));
lv.Text = resMngr.GetObject(someProperty, culture);
```

Comment: I eventually ended up doing something like this. Still didnt find a way to dynamically evaluate a resource key in the .ASPX page tho :/.

Comment: what is "SupertextCommon.Default" ?

Comment: Getting "Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Resources.BF_Resources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "AEWebClient" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed." Error

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me in a GridView using a property of its datasource:

```
<%# GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", Eval("SomeProperty").ToString()) %>
```

You can also use concatenation to build the key, e.g.:

```
<%# GetGlobalResourceObject("Resource", "SomePrefix" & Eval("SomeProperty").ToString()) %>
```